# TypeScript [Warning] transpiling to CommonJS, consider setting module: "system" in typescript Options

Tags: angular, typescript

Using Angular 2, I'm getting a warning in Chrome console:

> TypeScript [Warning] transpiling to CommonJS, consider setting module: "system" in typescriptOptions to transpile directly to System.register format

I've serached the web thoroughly but couldn't find a solution or an article about this issue.

I did find [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) site, that mentions using:

```
--allowSyntheticDefaultImports  (boolean)
```

as

```
module === "system"
```

I added to my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    //"module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "module": "system"
  }
}
```

But it did not help.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `module` to `system` option by setting `compilerOptions` of of `tsconfig.json` option.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "module": "system",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Find [**tsconfig.json docs here**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html)

Also you can do the same via command line by adding `--module system` in your command args.

Comment: @KobyDouek try removing comment(`//"module": "commonjs",`) from `tsconfig.json`.It makes JSON is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It should go into
`tsconfig.json`
They contain the settings and configurations for typescript transpilation 
Check [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

```
 "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
         "module": "system",

    //other settings
   }
```